# std::wait_until always required to block?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Is the 2-parameter version (i.e. the one without the predicate) of `std::wait_until` (C++11) required to block when the provided timeout `time_point` parameter is earlier than the "current time"?

If it does not block, does it still return `std::cv_status::timeout`?

Comment: If the mutex was signalled prior to the call, it will not block even if the timeout has not passed, returning std::cv_status::no_timeout. If the mutex was not signalled, the routine block until it is signalled OR the time expires. The return value is ::timeout only if the timeout expires before the mutex is signalled.

Comment: @JVene mutexes arn't signalled, but assuming you mean the condition variable, they don't retain any memory of being signaled, so wait_until() cannot know that the condition variable was signaled prior to the call.

Comment: In my opinion, the call blocks unless the time point specified is no greater than the current time point.

Comment: That's indeed the core of my question. I would like to know if the C++ standard states something about this, or if it's left to the standard library implementer.

Comment: Yes, `std::wait_until` always blocks until timeout, being signalled or spurious wakeup.  No answer because I don't have quotes from the standard, only [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until).

Comment: stefaanv, I wanted to know the behavior of `std::wait_until` if the timeout is _already_ behind the current time. In this condition, it's indeed not necessary to wait (or block)

Comment: @mamahuhu that might be want you wanted to know, but as far as I can tell that is not what you asked.

Comment: Yakk, I'm sorry, I might have been unclear. When the current time is ahead of the timeout, there's _no point_  in blocking. But does the standard still requires to block? Or not to block? Or is it unspecified?

Comment: The standard currently reads that cv_status::timeout is returned if the specified timeout expired. The Effects specifies that the function will unblock at the expiration of the timeout, meaning if you call wait_until when the timeout has already expired, the function will unblock.

Comment: @mama I understand that.  But *read your question* above (not in the comments).  **That is not what you asked** in your question.

Comment: JVene, Yakk and other contributors: sorry for the confusion! I was totally wrong and just plainly "flipped" the order between the current time and the timeout in my original question. I've just editted it, and (hopefully!) it is what I mean now. Thanks to Yakk for insisting!